# May I shut down xfce4-power-manager on Qubes OS 3.2? Is it going to cause security issue?

Tags: security, qubes

After some time use, I see that `xfce4-power-manager` is using a lot of resources (RAM and CPU). I think this is a natural thing. But given my limited computer ability then I thought to kill this process.

My question is:

1. Is it safe to kill `xfce4-power-manager` from Task Manager?
2. Will this action cause security issues for Qubes?